# Fetch Facebook Friend photos 2 for every friend in a single fql

Tags: facebook

I was trying

```
SELECT object_id, src_big,owner
    FROM photo WHERE pid
        IN ( SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid
        IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner
        IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM  friend WHERE uid1 = me()))) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 20
```

But it was giving only 2 photos but not for every friend.

Comment: You are a bit unclear. Are you saying you want to fetch 2 photos for every friend?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this should work !!

```
SELECT src_big_width,src_big_height, caption, owner, pid, src_big , src_small ,aid, created FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()))
```

You need `friends_photos` permission to access it. Also, check that you can see the photos in the Graph API by using the Graph API explorer to check there is data there which can be accessed via your access_token. This will help to rule out issues with your FQL query.